# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 + Repository - работа в отдельном проекте

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Есть некая модель:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? PostedDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public Post()
    {
        Comments = new HashSet<PostComment>();
    }
}


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime LastVisit { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }
}
```

и **Context**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Подскажите:
- Как это все обернуть в паттерн Repository?
- Как разнести все по сборкам(**Entities**(Та самая модель), **DataAccess** (Context, настройки БД), **Repository**(Паттерн репозиторий), **Services**(Сервисы для работы с ViewModel) и сама сборка **Web**(ASP.NET MVC 5) )?

Comment: Репозиторий - это посредник между доступом к данным и бизнес-логикой, представляющий интерфейс в виде коллекции объектов. У этот паттерн реализован классом `ApplicationDbContext`. Его свойство - `DbSet<Post> Posts` - это и есть "интерфейс в виде коллекции". поэтому не совсем понятно, что и во что вы хотите обернуть.

Comment: В моем понимании паттерн Repository — это абстракция которая позволяет думать о базе данных как о части приложения и реализует механизм для хранения, извлечения, обновления и поиска объектов в источнике данных. В идеале программа сохраняет и выбирает доменные объекты из Repository так, как будто это коллекция объектов в памяти. А `ApplicationDbContext` в свою очередь(как мне кажется) жестко привязывает нас к определенному ORM т.е. к EF. Еще хочется попробовать реализовать данный паттерн в качестве практики т.к. проект учебный. @PashaPash

Comment: DbSet<Post>  - это просто IQueryable<Post>. это абстракция, отвязанная от конкретного ORM и от конкретной базы данных. Вообще сам по себе любой современный ORM - это реализация Repository + Unit Of Work + Object-relational mapping. Т.е. по сути вы хотите реализовать Repository поверх Repository чтобы не зависеть от того, что внутри у вас Repository - это не имеет смысла. Есть некоторый смысл делать упрощенную реализацию-обертку ради юнит-тестов (отказываясь от части функционала EF). Но ради "просто тренировки" - точно нет.

Comment: Понятно, тогда вопрос снимается сам собой.Подскажите еще как  вынести непосредственно модель(классы БД и Identity.EF) в отдельную сборку. При этом не переопределяя все интерфейсы Identity(и вообще реально ли это?) @PashaPash

Comment: правой кнопкой на своём solution - add new project - class library. далее в основной сборке добавляете ссылки на новые библиотеки (во вкладке solution), таким образом сможете использовать свои интерфейсы. это если я правильно понял вопрос :-)

Answer (score 1):

Я пришел к такой структуре решения. Это базовая структура, содержащая только самое необходимое. Потом ее, разумеется, надо наполнить своими моделями.

```
Solution
|- Domain.Models
|  |- User
|
|- Domain.Services
|  |- IUnitOfWork
| 
|- ApplicationServices
|  |- IUserService
|
|- Infrastructure
|  |- Data
|  |  |- DatabaseContext
|  |  |- UnitOfWork
|  |
|  |- DBO
|  |  |- ApplicationUser
|  |  |- UserProfile
|  |
|  |- Services
|     |- UserService
|      
|- ASP.NET MVC Project
```

- `Domain.Models` - это собственно модели предметной области, с бизнес-логикой
- `IUserService`  - это интерфейс сервиса пользователей, который имеет методы "Регистрация", "Вход", "Выход" итп
- `User` и `DBO` - я в БД храню раздельно профиль юзера (сопутствующую информацию) и модель Identity, делаю маппинг. Это сделано для того, чтобы в Domain не было зависимости от IdentityUser
- `UserService` - реализация `IUserService`, собственно вся логика регистрации, входа и пр.

Потом с используете Dependency Injection, чтобы внедрить интерфейс `IUserService` в свои контроллеры или другие сервисы.

#### Примечание

Допустим, что `IUserService` примерно такой:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    Task Register(RegisterModel user, bool isPersist = false);
    Task Login(LoginModel user);
    Task Logout();
}
```

Тут есть классы

- RegisterModel
- LoginModel

Если бы все было в одном проекте, то они однозначно были бы ViewModels. Но т.к. уровень `ApplicationServices` не зависит от ASP.NET проекта, то модели вида использовать нельзя. Я вижу два варианта:

- Объявить их в `Domain` (не слишком идеологически верно)
- Объявить их там же, где и использующий их интерфейс - в `ApplicationServices`